# Build.xml file doesn't exist in Apache ANT folder

Tags: web-services, deployment, ant

I want to deploy webservices using AXIS2 standalone, I neither want to use servlet containers nor IDE.

I download Apache Ant from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi but the downloaded ant folder doesn't have build.xml file?

What is the solution? How can I deploy my webservices without using Ant???

Answer (score 0):

There's no `build.xml` because it's a **Binary Distribution**. There's nothing to build You unzip the file, and you have Ant on your system. On Windows, you'll need to adjust your `%PATH%` environment variable and set up an `%ANT_HOME%` environment variable. Actually, you need to do the same with Unix and Mac OS X too.

Now, if you want a **Source Distribution**, go to the [Source Distributions](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi) page. There, you will find a `build.xml`. Run that `build.xml` with Ant, and you get ...well... Ant.

Ant is used to compile Java based projects into classfiles, jars, wars, ears, and other Java world binaries. It can deploy, but you'll have to write your own `build.xml` to do just that.

I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking to deploy a project using Axis2? I'm not a developer, but Axis2 is something you use when building a Java project, and not a deployment tool itself. You use Axis2 to create web-based services.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to write your `build.xml` to build your webservice project.

From  http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi  you'll get an executable "ant".

By running `ant` on the command line, then Ant will build the project based on `build.xml` content.